How to browse to local_file.html#anchor fragments on the ChromeOS Linux command line?
nurdsborough@penguin$ ls
info.html
nurdsborough@penguin$ garcon-url-handler info.html        #works
nurdsborough@penguin$ garcon-url-handler info.html#anchor #fails

What is the workaround?

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/354503001

Use
nordsburg@penguin$ realpath info.html#anchor |
  sed s!^!file://! | xargs garcon-url-handler

I.e.,
nordsburg@penguin$ garcon-url-handler \
file:///mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/blabla/info.html#anchor

And lo and behold, the Chrome browser will indeed jump to the #anchor!
ChromeOS 130.
